# TypeScript: how to trick compiler when adding library without definitions?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find out how to 'trick' the compiler into thinking that I am using some definitions.

I have the following in my constructor:

```
nv.addGraph(()=> {...})
```

And before my class I put:

```
public nv:nv;
```

And in my model I have:

```
export interface nv{
    addGraph:any;
    models:any;
    utils:any;
}
```

However, I still get an error:

```
 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'nv'.
```

I was already trying different approach, by creating the class:

```
export class nv{
    addGraph:any
}
```

But then I get the following error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'addGraph' does not exist on type 'typeof nv'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `declare var` and you don't need any TypeScript class:

```
declare var nv;

nv.addGraph(()=> {
   // something here
});
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=declare%20var%20nv%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Anv.addGraph(()%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20something%20here%0D%0A%7D)%3B)]

Answer (score 0):

You can use type declaration:

```
declare class nv {
    addGraph: string;
}

var c = nv();
```

This compiles, but will work correctly only if you will load corresponding library.